# SSE3/SSSE3 + AES/RDRAND/RDSEED under Sun Studio

Tags: cryptography, aes, solaris, sunstudio

I'm working under Sun Studio 12.3 on SunOS 5.11 (Solaris 11.3). I'm tuning a script that includes negative tests, and that includes odd combinations of CPU features. We do this to understand if and how we fail; and to ensure there are [no unexpected surprises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

I'm trying to figure out a way to enable the native instruction set plus AES, RDRAND and RDSEED. The native instruction set is courtesy Xeon 5100's, which is effectively SSE3/SSSE3 plus some additional instructions.

Compiling all source files with `/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC -DNDEBUG -g3 -xO2 -template=no%extdef -native -m64 -KPIC -xarch=aes -D__AES__=1` results in:

```
$ ./cryptest.exe
ld.so.1: cryptest.exe: fatal: cryptest.exe: hardware capability (CA_SUNW_HW_1) unsupported: 0x1000000  [ SSE4.2 ]
Killed
```

This is kind of expected because Sun Studio assumes a progression of features and availability. When I modify the makefile to build `cpu.cpp` (used for feature tests), `rijndael.cpp` (provides AES implementation), and `test.cpp` (performs the testing) with `-xarch=aes`, the program still crashes because SSE4 is creeping into `test.cpp`.

I tried to use `-xarch=aes -D__AES__=1 -xarch=no%sse4_1 -xarch=no%sse4_2` to remove unwanted instruction sets, but it failed to compile as expected. `no%sse4_1` simply comes from `-template=no%extdef` because the `no%` prefix appears to be the way to turn things off.

How do I use SSE3/SSSE3 with the addition of AES/RDRAND/RDSEED under Sun Studio? Is it even possible?

---

The pattern we use, which has worked well up until now, is to combine compile time support with runtime support. So AES code will look like:

```
#if (__AES__ >= 1) || (SUNPRO_CC >= 0x512)
# define HAVE_AES 1
#endif

#if defined(HAVE_AES)
if (HasAES())
{
    // Optimized implementation
    ...
    return;
}
#endif
{
    // Fall into C/C++ implementation
    ...
}
```

For compilers like Clang and GCC, we simply [`-march=native -maes -mrdrnd -mrdseed`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh#L1911). I was happy to accept no cross-polination occurred.

Then I cam across two messages on Oracle's message boards indicating RDRAND is broken under Sun Studio 12.3 and 12.4 ([here for 12.3](http://community.oracle.com/thread/2565486?start=0&tstart=0) and [here for 12.4](http://community.oracle.com/thread/3539230?start=0&tstart=0)). So I have to ensure RDRAND is enabled to ensure its being tested, and that requires `-xarch=aes`.

---

Based on [_mm_aeskeygenassist_si128 intrinsic requires at least -xarch=aes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37746363), this may not be possible. This question is effectively due diligence to ensure we are doing everything we can to ensure a trouble free experience.

---

```
$ isainfo -v
64-bit amd64 applications
        ssse3 ahf cx16 sse3 sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov amd_sysc cx8 tsc fpu 
32-bit i386 applications
        ssse3 ahf cx16 sse3 sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, I have created an AES+SSSE3 binary for you.

```
$ cat tmp.c
#include 
#include 
#include 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // SSE2
   int64_t x[2];
   __m128i y = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)x);

   // AES
   __m128i z = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(y,0);

   return 0;
}

$ cat tmp2.c
#include 
#include 
void foo(void)
{       
        __m128i x;
        x       =  _mm_hadd_epi16 (x, x);
}

$ cc tmp.c tmp2.c -xarch=aes
tmp.c:
tmp2.c:

$ file a.out
a.out:          ELF 32-bit LSB executable 80386 Version 1 [AES SSSE3 SSE2 SSE], dynamically linked, not stripped
```

The Hardware Capabilities bits are assinged by the compiler 
depending on the actual presence of insructions in the final executable.

So **tmp.o** has **AES** bit assigned. And **tmp2.o** has up to **SSSE3** bits assined.

When linked together they produce **[AES SSSE3]** binary. Because **HWCAP** bits are **OR**ed together.